# Reuse Asp MVC view in multiple applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to reuse partial view in multiple ASP MVC applications. Is it possible to do that?
I have some partialview.cshtml which uses MyViewViewModel.cs and lots of typescripts/javascripts.

Is it possible to reuse all this code in different application?

If so, how I use views from external assembly?

Comment: Yeah it's possible.

Comment: okay, but how? how I use view from different assembly?

Comment: create partial view and pass model to it, `Html.RenderPartial("partialView",new Model());`

Comment: @Dalton but I want to use partial view which I've already written in different application. How can I use it from other assembly?

Comment: @Maarty you'd have to implent your own 'CustomVirtualPathProvider '  this answer can help you in process [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407406/2278873)

Answer (score 1):

look at razor generator:  https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator

and look for samples in the internet